# Mod rewrite error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm facing issue in rewriting URL. I have tried the top results mod rewrite generator sites from Google but none of them have solved my issue.

My current url is:

http://localhost/detail.php?uri=short-link&id=12

I want to make it:

http://localhost/detial/short-link-12

My current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^detail/([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ detail.php?uri=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: @umka 404 File not found

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Issue is still there `404 file not found`

Comment: There's a slash `/` missed after `^detail`.

Comment: @umka yes I add the slash does not work.

Comment: RewriteRule ^detail\/(.*)-(\d+)$ detail.php?uri=$1&id=$2 [L]

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Thanks dear. I works now :)
Can you add proper answer. I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MarkShevchenko for pointing me in the right direction.

Solution:

```
RewriteRule ^detail\/(.*)-(\d+)$ detail.php?uri=$1&id=$2 [L]
```